# Database fetching image and re-upload image issue in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm using core php, Actually,i'm fetching image from database and showing the image after any images changes and upload means not happening please help some one.

Here  my fetching image query:

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_master_property.*,tbl_master_inventory.rent,tbl_master_inventory.sharing_type,tbl_master_inventory.Advance  FROM tbl_master_property JOIN tbl_master_inventory ON tbl_master_property.pg_id=tbl_master_inventory.pg_id WHERE tbl_master_property.`name`='$values_post'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $pg_id = $row['pg_id'];
    $event_image = $row['event_image'];
}
```

Here showing image and uploading:

```
<form class="col-lg-12" method="post" action="updatefunction.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <div class="button-wrap col-lg-6">
        <div class="image-upload">
            <label for="file-input">
                <input type='file' name='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
                <img id="blah" name="image" src="http://localhost/rentozy/admin/<?=$event_image?>" width="175" height="200" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrap col-lg-6">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess btn-lg" value="Submit" name="login_sub">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here posting image anther file:
  not posting image here please help

```
if (isset($_POST['login_sub']))
{
    $id = $_POST['values'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get image data using $_FILES not in $_POST variable.

You will get new uploaded image data using $_FILES['file'] according to your code.

If you want to get image url form below code in your another file

```
<img id="blah" name="image" src="http://localhost/rentozy/admin/<?=$event_image?>" width="175" height="200" />
```

Then you have to add below given code in your code

```
<input type="hidden" name="image" value="http://localhost/rentozy/admin/<?=$event_image?">
```